# Interval hour type for a postgres column doesn't send error when inserting minute or second

Tags: postgresql

I defined one of my column as follow

```
  ALTER TABLE toto
    ADD COLUMN period INTERVAL HOUR DEFAULT '24 hour',
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_period CHECK (period BETWEEN INTERVAL '0 hour' AND INTERVAL '48 hour');`
```

The thing I want is to send an error when the interval that I want to insert is not an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce an hour-type input, you'll want to add `... AND period = date_trunc('hour', period)` to your check constraint:

```
   alter table toto
add constraint check_period
         check (period = date_trunc('hour',period) and
                period between interval '0 hour' and interval '48 hour');
```

However, the `INTERVAL HOUR` data type definition for your table will cast any input to `INTERVAL HOUR` before performing any checks against it.  Therefore, you'll want to drop the `period` column and re-define it as an `INTERVAL` type and not an `INTERVAL HOUR` type:

```
edb=# alter table toto drop column period;
ALTER TABLE
edb=# alter table toto add column period interval;
ALTER TABLE
edb=# alter table toto add constraint check_period check (period = date_trunc('hour',period) and period between interval '0 hour' and interval '48 hour');
ALTER TABLE
edb=# insert into toto values (1,'foo','10 hour 1 minute'::interval);
ERROR:  new row for relation "toto" violates check constraint "check_period"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, foo, 10:01:00).
```